# Google Cloud Data Fusion Datastore Node: Missing or insufficient permissions on Get Schema

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to create a new pipeline in *Google Cloud Data Fusion* where the first node in my pipeline is a *Datastore* node.  I would like that node to load all data from a particular Datastore *kind* and then pass the data to the next node for some other work.

My problem is that I am unable to get the **Get Schema** feature of the Datastore node to succeed.  I do believe that I am doing everything correctly, but a severe lack of documentation on this node type is not making things any easier.  I have my *Project ID* and *Service Account File Path* fields set to “auto-detect”, and a valid *Kind* name entered, but when I click the **GET SCHEMA** button (or try to Validate the Datastore node properties) I get an “*Unable to fetch data from Datastore: Missing or insufficient permissions*” error.

Has anyone had any experience with this issue before?  And even better yet, arrived at a solution?

I have Googled this error extensively and tried all sorts of options with service account permissions, but with no success.  These are the role permissions I have given my *App Engine default service account* (PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com):

- Cloud Data Fusion API Service Agent
- Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin
- Cloud Datastore User
- Cloud Storage for Firebase Service Agent
- Editor
- Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent
- Firebase Rules Viewer
- Firebase Service Management Service Agent
- Service Account Token Creator

Comment: Can you try again after giving the 'Dataproc Administrator' and '[Cloud Datastore Owner](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam)'' roles to the service account?.

Comment: I added those roles but it did not make any difference.  To be honest I'm not even sure if the Data Fusion Studio is running in the context of the App Engine default service account, and I can't find any documentation to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Could you give the Dataproc Administrator and Cloud Datastore Owner roles to the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/service-accounts) `service-CUSTOMER_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa- datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com`? If that does not resolve the error, give the same roles to `CUSTOMER_PROJECT_NUMBER- compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` too. Let me know if this solves your issue or not.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.  In the end I decided to go for a different solution due the crazy cost of keeping a live Datafusion Instance.  I did not try to resolve this issue using any of the suggestions sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose this types of error you usually need a stack trace and more details. I can recommend 2 approaches to get the extended diagnostics:

- Check system services logs in System Admin, especially Wrangler and Pipeline Studio
- If you find nothing over there, run a preview run. Even if you don't have full schema, you can just remove the schema altogether and let it figure it out. This way you can get logs with more information